# Is it possible to create a default .profile or .bash_profile with default configuration intact on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

In Ubuntu, I can get the default `.bashrc` by copying from the `/etc/skel` folder:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

This is extremely helpful for me as it gives me all the options and configuration already setup and properly commented.

Is there a similar feature for macOS (currently using macOS Sierra)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On user creation, the home directory contents are copied from a directory `/System/Library/User\ Template/<language>` (where language is for example `English.lproj`), so you could copy the original file using:

```
sudo cp /System/Library/User\ Template/<language>/<file> ~/
```

The problem is that `.bashrc` is non-existent in the default profile, so you can just delete it from your home directory to get the initial state.

<sup>Though you might check your installation to be 100% sure.</sup>

Comment: Note that there is some standard setup, but it's in /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc rather than in each user's own shell init files.

Comment: I think you should rather post this comment under the question. For me it's clear that OP asks specifically for the files in the home directory, even using an example from Ubuntu. Global rc-files are not specific to macOS, they are used in Ubuntu as well. I have no reason to believe OP asks for the files in `/etc`.

Comment: @techraf Thanks for posting your answer techraf! I didn't know about the original files template, that was very helpful. Is there a way to get the content of the initial state for .profile though? I just need to know what configurations are set as default.

Comment: `.profile` does not exist by default either. If you have any doubts you can just create a new user account and manually verify its configuration.

Comment: The only files in `/System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj` for me are `.CFUserTextEncoding` and `Library` directory. I have no `.bashrc` (which is expected) or `.bash_profile`, so I'm unsure where those files are being copied over upon a new user creation. I'm on macOS Monterey 12.4.